# Getting the maximum recursion 100 error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query functioning properly for less than 100 dates.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @startDate1 NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @endDate1 NVARCHAR(max)

SET @startDate = '2023/04/01'
SET @endDate = '2023/12/31'
SET @startDate1 = '2023/04/01'
SET @endDate1 = '2023/12/31';

WITH dates(date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, [date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE date < @enddate 
)
SELECT 
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + Quotename((CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [date], 103))) AS [Date]
                   FROM dates 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).Value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

I get this error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Tried using the option (maxrecursion 0) but it is showing syntax error in SQL Server.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why not *not* use recursion and use a tally instead? Then you *can't* have a maximum recursion error *and* the SQL is more performant.

Comment: Or, better yet, just get the dates from your calendar table; you do have a calendar table, right?

Comment: Also, why are you defining some of your date and time data types as a `nvarchar(MAX)`? What "date" is there that's over 4,000 characters in length? Date and time data types exist and should be used for date and time values, *not* a string based data type, and certainly not a `MAX` length one.

Comment: The `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` should be used at the end of the query.

Comment: I see you have discovered `date` is not the best choice of a column name `[date]`

Comment: Getting a new error now - Cannot create a row of size 9631 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

Comment: Are you trying to create a table with 274+ columns, @Anup ... *Why*? Sounds like what we actually have is a [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). I *assumed* the need was for a dynamic pivot for *display* purposes (which should really be done in the **display** layer), not to create a severely denormalised table.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comments, there's no need for recursion here; it is one of the *slowest* ways of achieving your goal (only better than a loop). Just query your calendar table. Also, I *assume* you are on a recent version of SQL Server, and so have access to `STRING_AGG`?

```sql
DECLARE @startDate date,
        @endDate date,
        @cols AS NVARCHAR(max), -- Not used?
        @query AS NVARCHAR(max), -- Not used?
        @startDate1 date,
        @endDate1 date;

SET @startDate = '20230401';
SET @endDate = '20231231';
SET @startDate1 = '20230401'; -- Not used?
SET @endDate1 = '20231231'; -- Not used?

SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),QUOTENAME(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CT.CalendarDate,103))),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [date]) --nvarchar(MAX) as if the string ends up longer than 4,000 you'll get an error
FROM dbo.CalendarTable CT
WHERE CT.CalendarDate >= @startDate
  AND CT.CalendarDate < @endDate;
```

If you *don't*, for some reason, have a calendar table then make one (how is beyond the scope of this question, but there are 1,000's of articles out there on how to achieve this).

If, for some reason, you can't make a Calendar Table (and the person who can refuses to for reasons undisclosed) then, as I mentioned in the comments *don't* use recursion. Instead use a Tally, it is *far* more performant. I switch back to the "old" `FOR XML PATH('')` method here, incase you are still using SQL Server 2016-:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY,@startDate,@endDate))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4), --Up to 10,000 rows. Add more cross joins for more rows
Calendar AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @startDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),C.CalendarDate,103))
              FROM Calendar C
              ORDER BY C.CalendarDate
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

---

Of course, none of this should be being done in the SQL layer at all. The above looks like you want a dynamic pivot, but if you *do* want one column per date, then that's a task for the **display** layer, *not* SQL layer. How you achieve that is a different question entirely though.

Comment: This is an obvious snark, but you're using the old pre-'92 style joins!

Comment: Yeah, that's intentional, as it's a `CROSS JOIN` @siggemannen .

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty fix is to add `MAXRECURSION`:

```
...
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

But you shouldn't be using recursion to build a simple sequence (be it numbers or dates), and on 2017+ [you really shouldn't be using clunky `FOR XML PATH` anymore](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/02/t-sql-queries/string-aggregation-over-the-years-in-sql-server).

In SQL Server 2022 (or Azure SQL DB/MI) [you can use `GENERATE_SERIES()`](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/generate-series-to-build-a-set/). I assume since you are using `@cols` that you actually need to apply `QUOTENAME()` to each date in the output:

```
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(max), 
  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10), 
  DATEADD(DAY, value, @startDate), 103))), ',')
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate));
```

If you're on 2017 or 2019:

```
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(varchar(max),d),',')
FROM
(
  SELECT d = QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),
             DATEADD(DAY,rn-1,@startDate),103))
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT
    (
      REPLICATE('.',DATEDIFF(DAY,@startDate,@endDate)), '.'
    ) AS x
  ) AS y
) AS z;
```

`@cols` in both cases:

```
[01/04/2023],[02/04/2023],[03/04/2023], ...
... many more dates ...
... ,[29/12/2023],[30/12/2023],[31/12/2023]
```

- Examples demonstrated in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-lDZDG4j)